# Phonegap:Adding custom icons in tabbar

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, uitabbar

I need add some icons to tabbar buttons in my iPhone App.I'm using Phonegap 1.1.0 framework with native plugins.I tried many things like :

- nativeControls.createTabBarItem(tab.name, tab.name, ‘icon.png’,
  options);
- nativeControls.createTabBarItem(tab.name, tab.name,
  ‘tabButton:’+tab.name+”.png”, options);

but none of these worked.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have my tab bar set up:

```
var nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls; 
var options = {"onSelect":onTabBarItemSelect}; 

nativeControls.createTabBar();

nativeControls.createTabBarItem("radio", "4ZzZfm Radio", "/www/images/radio.png", options);
nativeControls.createTabBarItem("guide", "Program guide", "/www/images/calendar.png", options);
nativeControls.createTabBarItem("appsettings", "Settings", "/www/images/preferences.png", options);

nativeControls.showTabBarItems("radio","guide","appsettings");      
nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("radio");
nativeControls.showTabBar();
```

I think the problem is your path to the images. The NativeControls plugin needs a "fullish" path starting from the www folder as above.